# SQL Query with two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as following

```
Point:                       ListMember:
index   description          indexParent     indexChild
--------------------         ---------------------------
1       ABC                  333             1
2       DEF                  333             2
3       GHI                  444             1
333     Hello                444             2
444     Bye                  444             3
555     Welcome
```

An example of result table that i am looking for

```
Result:
Index     description        listSize    descriptionChild
333       Hello                2           ABC
333       Hello                2           DEF 
444       Bye                  3           ABC
444       Bye                  3           DEF
444       Bye                  3           GHI
555       Welcome              0
```

I am new to database and still learning SQL so i am not quite sure how to do the select to obtain the result i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the following query should work for you ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cd382/4/0)):

```
SELECT p1.[index], p1.description, 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM ListMember ls
    WHERE ls.indexParent = p1.[index]
  ) AS listSize,
  p2.description AS descriptionChild
FROM Point p1
LEFT JOIN ListMember l ON l.indexParent = p1.[index]
LEFT JOIN Point p2 ON l.indexChild = p2.[index]
WHERE p1.[index] NOT IN 
(
  SELECT indexChild FROM ListMember
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your results should be 333 Hello. You have to do two left joins (for 555 with no children).

psuedo code:

```
Select p.index, p.description, p2.index as listsize, p2.description as descriptionchild
  from point p
  left join listmember l
    on p.index = l.indexparent
  left join point p2
    on l.indexchild = p2.index
```

Comment: I didn't take into account the count. Just the index. But, the joins seem to be the main part of your question.

Comment: **Bob Blackburn**, not only does your query not have the listsize, it does not exclude the the child indexes from the result [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cd382/10).

Answer (score 0):

Due to using the unfortunate column name `index`, you have to include brackets every time you refer to that column. This is working for me:

```
SELECT P.[index] AS [Index],
    P.description,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ListMember WHERE indexParent = P.[index]) AS listSize,
    P2.description AS descriptionChild
FROM Point P
LEFT JOIN ListMember LM ON LM.indexParent = P.[index]
LEFT JOIN Point P2 ON P2.[index] = LM.indexChild
WHERE P.[index] NOT IN (SELECT indexChild FROM ListMember)
ORDER BY P.[index]
```